# Why is onDrop and onDragOver not getting triggered in React Component when ran in chrome browser? Version of chrome: 97.0.4692.71

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I am trying to print inside these event callbacks as you can see in the code, even they are not getting printed. I tried working this out with onDragEnd but the id procured from currentTarget in onDragEnd is the same as onDragStart. So I need onDrop for this which is not getting triggered. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong, here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { MoreVert } from '@material-ui/icons';

function newFunc(){

const [dragId, setDragId] = useState('')
const [pendingTask, setPendingTask] = useState([{order: 1, id: 'task1'}, {order: 2, id: 'task2'}, {order: 3, id: 'task3'}])

const handleDrag = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.currentTarget.id)
    setDragId(evt.currentTarget.id)
}

const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    event.preventDefault()
}

const handleDrop = (evt) => {
    alert('dropped')
    console.log(evt)
    const dragBox = pendingTask.find((task) => task.id === dragId);
    const dropBox = pendingTask.find((task) => task.id === evt.currentTarget.id);

    const dragBoxOrder = dragBox.order;
    const dropBoxOrder = dropBox.order;

    const newPendingTaskState = pendingTask.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === dragId) {
            task.order = dropBoxOrder;
        }
        if (task.id === evt.currentTarget.id) {
            task.order = dragBoxOrder;
        }
        return task;
    });

    setPendingTask(newPendingTaskState);
}
const handlePendingTaskClick = () => {
// doing something
}

return(
    <div>
{pendingTask.length ? 
        pendingTask.map((elem, ind)=>{
        return(
            <div
                style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                key={ind}
                onClick={() => handlePendingTaskClick(elem)}
            >
            <div
                draggable={true}
                onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                onDragStart={handleDrag}
                onDrop={handleDrop}
                id={elem.id}  
            >
                <MoreVert />
            </div>
            <div>
                {elem.workflow}
            </div>
            </div>
        )                              
        }):null
    }
</div>
)
}

export default newFunc
```

I am using react hooks and inbuilt HTML drag and drop API.
.
Edit 1: It is only not working in the latest chrome browser, version: 97.0.4692.71.

Comment: onDrop is fired by elements when draggables (e.g. your div) are dropped onto afaik. Can you try to use onDragEnd on your div instead? Or use onDrop on your actual drop target maybe?

Comment: @NickG If you read the code above, that is what I am doing... And I mentioned earlier why I can't use onDragEnd. if you know some other way to do it please share.

Comment: I dont quite get what your issue is. I've created a fiddle based on your example, and it seems to work. Only things i found that you are missing are unique keys that are not the index and some kind of reordering of your tasks.

Probably the material ui-icon is blocking the onDrop event. To prevent this, you can add pointer-events: false  to your css of the icon.
https://jsfiddle.net/seth_reloaded/1mLf7wj4/

Comment: Oh I just checked in another browser than chrome it seems to be working. It seems to be an issue with my chrome browser. But thanks @NickG